# Offsetting the ActiveCell in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I would like to declare 'MyRange' in the code below by using the activecell and offset functions.

I receive an error.
[image]

In the code I would like MyRange to equal the cell that is five columns in front of the activecell.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)
```

Comment: `Offset(0, -5)` means you refer 5 columns to the left and in case your active cell is in column 5,4 or less you try to refer to a cell with column 0, -1, ... which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Offset(0, -5)` refers to a cell which is five columns to the left. In case the column of the active cell is less or equal 5 `Offset(0, -5)` refers to a non-existing column.

In order to avoid the run time error you could check if the column of the active cell is greater than 5 like that

```
If ActiveCell.Column > 5 Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Storax that worked! I'm using "MyRange" in a vlookup formula.When I FillDown that Vlookup now every Vlookup is referencing the same cell. Do you know what I can do to reference :ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3) for every new row? I can share my code with you if that will help/

Comment: Please create a new post with neccessary information.